# Client id method javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

```
 <input type="text" id="txtFirstName" runat="server" class="textReg"                                         
 onblur="javascript:validate_input(<%=txtFirstName%>,'imgFirstNameS','imgFirstNameE');" />`
```

I want to send control id to my javascript function

like `ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtFirstName`

or

```
function validate_input(control, success, error) {
control = document.getElementById('<%='+control+'.ClientID %>');
}
```

is it possible ?

Answer (score 3):

Why send the Id if the next thing you do is get the item by Id. Just put 'this' as first parameter.

```
<input type="text" id="txtFirstName" runat="server" class="textReg"  
onblur="validate_input(this,'imgFirstNameS','imgFirstNameE');" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jQuery remove your inline js handler and put something like

If you want to hook the event for a bunch of textboxes having the class `testReg` then you can do something like

```
$("input:text.textReg").blur(function(){
    validate_input(this, 'imgFirstNameS', 'imgFirstNameE');
});
```

If you want this for the textbox with id `txtFirstName` only then you can have something like

```
$("<%= txtFirstName.ClientID %>").blur(function(){
   validate_input(this, 'imgFirstNameS', 'imgFirstNameE');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer the direct question, here is the proper syntax for this:

```
<input type="text" id="txtFirstName" runat="server" class="textReg"                                         
 onblur="validate_input('<%=txtFirstName.ClientID%>', 'imgFirstNameS', 'imgFirstNameE');" />
```

However TurBas idea is better, pass `this` and use it directly.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <input type="text" id="txtFirstName" runat="server" class="textReg"                                           
onblur="javascript:validate_input(<%=txtFirstName.ClientID%>,'imgFirstNameS','imgFirstNameE');" />
```